# Httparty displaying HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, httparty

I am using httparty gem to get wp-json date from a wordpress site to my Rails application.

Here is my controller that gets the json info:

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

class ConnectionController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
  end

  def thirty_days
    get_thirty_days
  end

  private

  def query_wordpress_category(wordpress_category)
    @response = HTTParty.get("http://thriveconnection.com/wp-json/posts?filter[category_name]=#{wordpress_category}&filter[order]=date")
  end

  def get_thirty_days
    query_wordpress_category("30-days")
    @thirty_days = JSON.parse(@response.body)
  end

end
```

Here is what it gets displayed: http://d.pr/i/1jMEq

Here is my view:

```
<% @thirty_days.each do |article| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <a href="<%= article['link'] %>" target="_blank">
          <img src="<%= article['featured_image']['source'] %>" alt="" class="img-responsive thumbnail" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <strong class="title-font">
          <a href="<%= article['link'] %>" target="_blank">
            <%= article['title'] %>
          </a>
        </strong>

        <span class="small-font">Published Date <%= article['date'] %></span>
        <br /><br />
        <%= article['excerpt'] %>
        <br /><br />
        <a href="<%= article['link'] %>" target="_blank">
          <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>Read the Article
        </a>
      </div>
    </div><!-- END .row -->
    <% end %>
```

Here is my problem, the excerpt from wordpress gets displayed as an html.  How can I display that so the HTML tags don't show up.  Also, is there any way I can format the date to mm/dd/yyyy format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark the strings that you don't want escaped as [`html_safe`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe) which allows the Rails view processor to know not to escape them.  Be warned, if you don't escape them then you open your users up to various hack attempts by the other site by including a malicious packet in the strings you retrieve.

So, eg.

```
<%= article['title'].html_safe %>
```

Comment: Is there another safe way to display the parsed json data in the view opposed to html_safe or raw?

Comment: No particular reason, I just want to go with the most safe route and best practices.

Comment: Oh right, you mean to mitigate the issues I mentioned with not being able to trust the HTML?  Best bet is to write a sanitizer, [see how to use the Rails sanitizer features here](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer)

Answer (score 1):

Also as for date format I used

```
<%= Date.parse(article["date"].strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>
```